# Querying a large mongodb collection in real-time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

We have a service that allow people to open a room and play YouTube songs while others are listening in real-time.

Among other collections in our MongoDB we have one to store songs user adding to the room's playlists, it calls: userSong. 
This collection holds records for all songs added for the combination of: user-room-song.

The code makes frequent queries to the collection in those major operations:

1. Loading current playlist (regular find with a trivial condition)
2. Loading random song for a room (using Mongo aggregation FW)
3. Loading room top songs (using Mongo aggregation FW)

Now, this table become big (+1m records) and things start become slow, AWS start sending us CPU utilization notifications more often and follow by `mongotop` the userSong collection makes the CPU high consumption mostly in READ operations.

We made some modifications in the collection indexes and it helps a bit but it's still not a solution, we need to find some other way to arrange the data cause it exponentially growing.

We tought about to split the userSong data into a low level segmentation, instead of by user-room-song to do it by collection of user-song for each room in the system, this will short the time to fetching data from the DB, now we need to decide how to do that:

1. Make a new collection for each room (roomUserSong) that will hold all user-song records for a particula room. this might be good for quick fetching but will create an unlimited new collectons in the database (roomusersong-1,roomusersong-2, ..., roomusersong-n) and we dont know if it's a good in practice or there are some others Mongo limitations in that kind of solution.
2. Create just 1 more collection in the DB with the following fields: 
   `{room: <roomId>, userSongs: [{userSong1, userSong2, ..., userSongN}]`, so each room will have it's own document and inside it a sub document (an Array) that holds all user-song records for this room. this will solve the previous issue (to create unlimited collections) but it'll be very hard to work with Mongoose (our ODM) alter cause (as far as i know) we cannot define a schema in advanced for this such data structure. also this is may tak us to the sub-document size limitation that is 16MB as far as understood.

It'll be nice to hear some advices from people who have Mongo experience with those kind situations:

1. Is +1m is really consider big and supposed to make this CPU utilization issues? (using AWS m3.medium, one core)
2. What is the better solution approach form what introduced?
3. Any other ideas to make smart cache without change too much the code?

Thanks for helpers!